# Bootstrap navbar on focus expanding search box out of canvas

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, expand

I using bootstrap and have a search box on navbar (as shown on screenshot), when the box is on focus, it will expanding to certain width of values, but the width cannot be fit into the container (off canvas), and the expanding transition doesn't goes to right-to-left which is what I wanted,

Can it able to solve?

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li class="hidden">
            <a href="#top"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="page" href="#">item1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="page" href="#">item2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
    <div class="input-group stylish-input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <button type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>  
        </span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm searchbox" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
    </form>
    <!-- /.search -->

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.stylish-input-group .input-group-addon{
    background: #fff !important;
    padding: 5px !important;
}
.stylish-input-group .form-control{
    border-right: 0;
    border-left: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0; 
    border-color: #ccc;
}
.stylish-input-group button{
    border: 0;
    background: transparent;
}

input.searchbox {
    width: 130px !important;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: width 0.3s;
    transition: width 0.3s;
}

input.searchbox:focus {
    width: 130% !important;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: width 0.5s;
    transition: width 0.5s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you forgot to add a row in the navigation. Here is the fixed code:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
            <li class="hidden">
                <a href="#top"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="page" href="#">item1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="page" href="#">item2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
            <div class="input-group stylish-input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <button type="submit">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                    </button>
                </span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm searchbox" placeholder="Search">
            </div>
        </form><!-- /.search -->
    </div> <!-- /.col -->
</div> <!-- /.row -->
```

Hope it works :)